# Fail to install the "tidyverse" package

Tags: r

I am creating a plot using the ggplot() function in R Studio. For doing the job, I need to install the "tidyverse" package, but find installation failure. I will appreciate if you could solve the problem. The error messages are displayed in the console pane:

> install.packages("tidyverse")
>   Installing package into ‘C:/Users/cheol/OneDrive/문서/R/win-library/3.6’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   also installing the dependency ‘purrr’
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/purrr_0.3.3.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 426130 bytes (416 KB)
>   downloaded 416 KB
>
> trying URL 'https://cran.cnr.berkeley.edu/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/tidyverse_1.3.0.zip'
>   Content type 'application/zip' length 440226 bytes (429 KB)
>   downloaded 429 KB
>
> package ‘purrr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   Error in install.packages : ERROR: failed to lock directory ‘C:\Users\cheol\OneDrive\문서\R\win-library\3.6’ for modifying
>   Try removing ‘C:\Users\cheol\OneDrive\문서\R\win-library\3.6/00LOCK’

Comment: Try a different mirror. In Widows Explorer, you'll need to navigate to, and delete, the `00LOCK` directory otherwise you might get some more errors.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I am successful to install "tidyverse" as delete the "00LOCK" directory as you guide. Then I tried to load "tidyverse", but the following massages appear on the pane:                                                                             
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
네임스페이스 ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0는 이미 로드되었으나 >= 0.2.1가 필요합니다